How Do I get This Field Parameter To Work?
I watched a youtube video on field parameters and did the same setup as the tutorial suggested and mine still does not work. My goal is to have a dynamic Y-axis based on a slicer that I have selected. For some reason when I filter by utilizing the slicer nothing changes, HOWEVER when I do that and place the field parameter in the legend portion of the chart it shows that it was able to correctly identify the X-Axis parameter and properly correlate it to its values from the Y-Axis.. So I feel like I am close but may be missing one small detail.
This is what it looks like when I do NOT use a field parameter

This is what it looks like when I DO use a field parameter and try to filter it.

This is what it looks like when its in the legend area which lets me know that the field parameter was indeed properly correlated, but something is off. I want this to work in the Y-Axis so instead of the legend so for example it would generate a chart with the values being 0.062, 0.066, 0.068 and so on

Note: The names are obscured since this is for work.

Can you provide some data please?

@AmiraBedhiafi data example is here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hDLvtpsVsQGW6GV6fRPkIppOufbW7QugoPKpBYS2u78/pubhtml
The first tab is what I am using and the 2nd tab is what the data looked like before transformations. I want to be able to show the data for a specific value for each of the months and then filter by the values (P01, P02 etc) using one chart
